# Getting multiple node_modules in a docker container working with an ejected react app?

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have to use an ejected React CRA, and since there's multiple react ui projects within this app I'm working on, I'm trying to build a base container for the build scripts/dependencies and then use that base container for all the frontend instances so that maintaining those react webpack scripts are easier.

Github Repo: https://github.com/StupidIncarnate/test-containers

When I have it install the package.json for the actual ui project, it seems like the react scripts get confused by the multiple node_modules and can't access the node_modules where the webpack / babel stuff live.

Docker Layered Container Structure (Linux Containers)

```
usr
   src
      package.json
      node_modules
      scripts
      config
      app
         node_modules
         src
         public
         package.json
```

containers/app-local/ui/Dockerfile

```
FROM container-ui

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
#COPY ./app-local/ui/package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
#COPY ./app-local/ui/package-lock.json /usr/src/app/package-lock.json
#RUN npm install

COPY ./app-local/ui/src /usr/src/app/src
COPY ./app-local/ui/public /usr/src/app/public


# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src
```

If I uncomment out the copy packages and npm install lines, when I run the react app, I get this compiler error:

[CompilerError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoDuq.png)

But if I keep it commented out, I can't install packages needed just for that ui instance.

Comment: Files containing JSX syntax (such as your `<App />`) should use the `.jsx` extension instead of `.js`. It’s possible your transpiler is just looking at the extension and deciding that `<App />` is invalid in vanilla JS (which it is).

Comment: I mean, besides a few changes to the App.js, all these files come from CRA bootstrap, so they setup the scripts to look for js and jsx. Changing index.js => index.jsx doesn't fix the issue though